# How to Improve Dynamic Graphics3D Animation Performance

Tags: performance-tuning, graphics3d, dynamic

I have a simple animation of a 6-sided die that works as expected except that it runs too slow.  I have created 60 *frames* that I would like for it to show all frames at 30 frames per second.  I do not want to create a gif or other static representation as the spin of the die should be random even for the same die face.

```
dsDice = With[{faces = PolyhedronData["Cube", "Faces"]},
    With[{vertices = faces[[1, faces[[2, 1, #]]]]},
       <|
        "Face" -> {
          Texture[Image@
            Graphics[
             Text[Style[ToString[#], 200, Underlined, FontFamily -> "Verdana"]]]],
          Polygon[vertices,
           VertexTextureCoordinates -> 
            RotateLeft[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}},
             Switch[#, 1 | 2, 2, 5, 1, _, 3]]]
          },
        "NormalVector" -> 
         Subtract @@ vertices[[{1, 2}]]\[Cross]Subtract @@ 
           vertices[[{1, 3}]]
        |>
       ] & /@ Range[6]
    ] // Dataset;

roll[] :=
 With[{event = RandomInteger[{1, 6}]},
  {
   DynamicModule[{t = 1, spin = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, 3]},
    Dynamic[
     t = Max[0, t - 1/60];
     Deploy@
      Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Gray], 
        Rotate[Normal@dsDice[All, "Face"], t (5 \[Pi])/3, spin]},
       ViewPoint -> Normal@dsDice[event, "NormalVector"],
       Background -> LightGray,
       Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}},
       Boxed -> False,
       ImageSize -> Medium,
       RotationAction -> "Clip"]
     ]]
   ,
   event
   }
  ]
```

When `roll[]` is run the all the *frames* display but is refreshed too slow. I need a solution that just has the animation without any controls.  I tried to return an `Animate` with `AppearanceElements->None` but the controls were still visible.  Any ideas? Currently on version 11.0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The less in `Dynamic` the better, you only really need `Rotate` parameters there.
- Also, inexact numbers' calculations are faster.
- It is a good habit to use `Animator` for this type of FE related iterations. It is more verbose, gives better control and runs completely in the FrontEnd.
- Also in defining the faces in `dsDice` the animation will run faster if you do not convert the `Graphics` of the numbers into `Image`. (*Edmund update*)

```
roll[] :=  With[{ 
  event =  RandomInteger[{1, 6}]
  }, 
  { 
    DynamicModule[{t = 0,  spin = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, 3]},
      Column[{
        Animator[Dynamic[t], {0, 1}, AppearanceElements -> None, 
          AnimationRate -> .5, AnimationRepetitions -> 1
        ],
        Deploy @ Graphics3D[{
          EdgeForm[Gray], 
          Rotate[Normal@dsDice[All, "Face"], Dynamic[(1-t) (5. \[Pi])/3.], spin]
          }, 
          ViewPoint -> Normal@dsDice[event, "NormalVector"], 
          Background -> LightGray, 
          Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, 
          Boxed -> False, 
          ImageSize -> Medium, 
          RotationAction -> "Clip"
        ]
      }]
    ], 
    event
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Also note that things get even faster if the `Texture` is left as `Graphics` and not converted to `Image`.

Comment: @Edmund makes sense, haven't noticed that, thanks for a tip. Feel free to edit that answer with this fix too.